How to regroup Django commands in sub directories?
How can I regroup management commands?
I tried the following but the 2 commands are not discovered by Django.
I also tried with an import in the commands/__init__.py file without success.
myapp/
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            user_management/
                __init__.py
                create_user.py
                delete_user.py

